# Wildcard expansion for folder names?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

There is `*.*` for doing command for all of files, like:

```
C:\Data>attrib -s -h -r *.*
```

is there something like `*.*` but for folders?

For example the same "ATTRIB" command.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a:d
dir /a:d | find "Documents"
```

Where the first gives ya all the directories and the second (assuming you're in your home directory) gives you the documents dir and probably the junction for "My Documents".

For more complex tasks I'd recommend using PowerShell rather than cmd.exe.

The "/a:d" bit means kinda "file with the directory attribute".

Comment: *The "/a:d" bit means kinda "file with the directory attribute".* Actually, that is *exactly* what it means.

Comment: However, I'm not sure how well this answers the question as asked. Perhaps you can [edit] your answer to clarify how this would help the OP in some sort of general case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Depending on the command, there often is a parameter to work against folders instead of files. `*.*` means all files and folders, but it depends on the command. Alternatively, you can use FOR to execute a command on all folders and optionally subfolders.

If you tell us what you want to do, we can tell you what the best approach is and what the full command is.